# How to write equivalent of lambda expression in Java 1.7?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following code in Java 1.8.

```
solver.plugMonitor((IMonitorSolution) () -> solution.record(solver));
```

How can I convert this to Java 1.7 code without lambda?

Comment: What method is declared in `IMonitorSolution`?

Comment: The cast to `IMonitorSolution` is unnecessary.

Comment: I guess, every IDE has a “convert to inner class” refactoring action…

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `plugMonitor` method requires an argument of type `IMonitorSolution`, with some method `YMethod` that has no arguments :

```
solver.plugMonitor (new IMonitorSolution () {
                        public void YMethod () {
                            solution.record(solver);
                        }
                    });
```

Thanks to @Boann for correcting my error.

Comment: Thanks! works. I'm translating some Java 1.8 code to work with the current version of GWT, finally all works.